# Is it possible to add a placemark to a custom map via maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

What I'm trying to do is rendering a map via the JS API then, using the drawing controls feature, add a placemark to the map and finally save the placemark position somewhere.
This way the next map rendering could show the previous saved placemarks.
I though my placemarks could be saved in a google maps public/private map but I didn't find a way to do it. Is this possible to do it or do I have to save my placemarks in my DB or on a my  fusion table?

Comment: AFAIK there  is no API for managing myMaps. But using a FusionTable should be a good approach.